# C# wpf How do I call initializeComponent from Main

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am having an issue with a C# code. First, I'm not a C# developer, I've just been given this project and it's been really frustrating for me.
But the vendor has provided some code for us to run. Their code did not have `Main()` function, which I guess would be the entry point, so I am trying to add it based on the default code when you create a WPF project...in VS2012

Here is the code. This is the C# code of a xaml window. At the very end, you can see I am trying to add `Main()` to call `InitializeComponent`. But I am receiving some errors.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Shell;


namespace Interfaces.Connection {


/// <summary>
/// ConnectionDialog
/// </summary>
public partial class ConnectionDialog : System.Windows.Window, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector {
    
    
    #line 30 "..\..\MainWindow.xaml"
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1823:AvoidUnusedPrivateFields")]
    internal System.Windows.Controls.TextBox txtConnectionServer;
    
    #line default
    #line hidden
    
    
    #line 33 "..\..\MainWindow.xaml"
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1823:AvoidUnusedPrivateFields")]
    internal System.Windows.Controls.TextBox txtUsername;
    
    #line default
    #line hidden
    
    
    #line 36 "..\..\MainWindow.xaml"
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1823:AvoidUnusedPrivateFields")]
    internal System.Windows.Controls.TextBox txtContext;
    
    #line default
    #line hidden
    
    
    #line 39 "..\..\MainWindow.xaml"
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1823:AvoidUnusedPrivateFields")]
    internal System.Windows.Controls.PasswordBox txtPassword;
    
    #line default
    #line hidden
    
    
    #line 45 "..\..\MainWindow.xaml"
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1823:AvoidUnusedPrivateFields")]
    internal System.Windows.Controls.Button btnOk;
    
    #line default
    #line hidden
    
    
    #line 46 "..\..\MainWindow.xaml"
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1823:AvoidUnusedPrivateFields")]
    internal System.Windows.Controls.Button btnCancel;
    
    #line default
    #line hidden
    
    private bool _contentLoaded;
    
    /// <summary>
    /// InitializeComponent
    /// </summary>
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
    public void InitializeComponent() {
        if (_contentLoaded) {
            return;
        }
        _contentLoaded = true;
        System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/Interfaces.Connection;component/mainwindow.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
        
        #line 1 "..\..\MainWindow.xaml"
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);
        
        #line default
        #line hidden
    }
    
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Design", "CA1033:InterfaceMethodsShouldBeCallableByChildTypes")]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Maintainability", "CA1502:AvoidExcessiveComplexity")]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1800:DoNotCastUnnecessarily")]
    void System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target) {
        switch (connectionId)
        {
        case 1:
        this.txtConnectionServer = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)(target));
        return;
        case 2:
        this.txtUsername = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)(target));
        return;
        case 3:
        this.txtContext = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)(target));
        return;
        case 4:
        this.txtPassword = ((System.Windows.Controls.PasswordBox)(target));
        return;
        case 5:
        this.btnOk = ((System.Windows.Controls.Button)(target));
        
        #line 45 "..\..\MainWindow.xaml"
        this.btnOk.Click += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(this.btnOk_Click);
        
        #line default
        #line hidden
        return;
        case 6:
        this.btnCancel = ((System.Windows.Controls.Button)(target));
        
        #line 46 "..\..\MainWindow.xaml"
        this.btnCancel.Click += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(this.btnCancel_Click);
        
        #line default
        #line hidden
        return;
        }
        this._contentLoaded = true;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Application Entry Point.
    /// </summary>
    [System.STAThreadAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Interfaces.Connection.ConnectionDialog app = new Interfaces.Connection.ConnectionDialog();
        app.InitializeComponent();
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

}

One error I am getting is:

> Interfaces.Connection.ConnectionDialog' does not contain a constructor
> that takes 0 arguments.

Not sure what constructor would be and not sure what arguments I need to pass in.

Another error:

> Interfaces.Connection.ConnectionDialog' does not contain a defintion
> for 'Run' and no extension method 'Run' accepting a first argument of
> type Interfaces.Connection.ConnectionDialog' could be found(are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I just had .Run() copied over from the default code whenever you create a WPF C# project in VS. If it's not needed, I can take it out.

How can I `InitializeComponent` from the `Main()` in my scenario?
As said, I'm not a C# dev, so if you can please be as little as technical so that a beginner C# person would understand, that would be really really great!

And if you have further questions on clarification, I'll try my best to answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WPF is a complex framework in and of itself, and is not really suitable for the unexperienced. I suggest you learn C# basics by using some console or winforms applications and then when you feel comfortable with the language grab the WPF stuff.

Comment: lol..well I would, except this project has fallen in my hands...and at this point, we want to try to develop the API first before paying the 3rd party vendor.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that given the circumnstances you have very little chance of succeeding with that. WPF not only requires that you learn a new language (`XAML`) a new object model (`System.Windows.*`), but also a new programming methodology and pattern (`MVVM`). If you fail to grasp any of these concepts you have great chances for failure.

Comment: Is this all your code for `ConnectionDialog`? It says that it is `partial`. Can you locate the constructor and post that?

Answer (score 7):

First, the code you have posted looks like generated code. It should not be touched manually at all.

In addition, you do not need a `Main` method in a WPF application. When you just create a new WPF project, you don't have a `Main` method either. The framework generates that for you behind the scenes and shows the main window automatically. If you want to do something on application startup, the `App.xaml` file holds an `Application` object which has a `Startup` event. Use this instead of a `Main` method.

Also, `InitializeComponent` should automatically be called by the framework. There is no need to call it manually.

Comment: well, the code was given to us from 3rd party vendor. And I just copied over their stuff into a WPF. When I first created the WPF, it created a App.xaml and in it, it had class App, with Main() and initializeComponent()....but their code did not have this. So when I deleted that default App.xaml, it deleted the Main(), so then i got the error of saying ".....connection.exe' does not contain a static 'main' method suitable for an entry point. That's when I started trying to add the Main() to call initializeComponent()

Comment: There is a need to call InitializeComponent() manually if you need to completely re-render the window and all its descendants from the application code. For example when the style was changed...

Answer (score 2):

With regard to  the `Interfaces.Connection.ConnectionDialog does not contain a definition for 'Run'` error: the compiler is saying this because it's true. You don't have a Run method in that class. You're trying to call a nonexistent method. You should probably just take out the `app.Run();` line.

To call `InitializeComponent` from `Main()`, it looks like you're already doing it correctly. Your `app.InitializeComponent();` line is calling the correct method.

Comment: ok, thanks I took run() out. The first error I am getting is on the line above the app.InitializeComponent(). "new Interfaces.Connection.ConnectionDialog()...it's saying that does not contain constructor.....

Comment: Since the class is defined as partial, that means that there may be other files that also put methods/constructors into this class. Try to find any others and see if they have constructors.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know enough C# and your vendor does, let your vendor supply a *complete, compilable example*. That should be part of the deal, if it's not, make sure it gets part of it ASAP.

That may sound strange, but if I pay somebody to sell me a car, I would not be satisfied getting a trunk and two wheels, some wire and a shabby blueprint of how it might look once assembled. I want a fully functional car. No car, no deal. You should not make a deal that reads "some assembly required". You should buy a **product**, not a construction kit.

Comment: But maybe the incomplete crap costs $100 less than a working example... :)